# create new variable with ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement, variables

I want to create a new variable, that shows me if an activity was completed past a set deadline, i have panel data:

My df:

```
  completion day deadline activityid
1          0   1        2   1
2          0   2        3   1
3          1   3        2   2
4          1   4        5   3
5          0   3        1   4
6          1   1        2   4
7          0   2        3   5
8          0   3        4   5
9          1   4        5   6
10         1   5        6   7
```

So i would like to have the output to be like this:

```
  overdue
1       0
2       0
3       1
4       0
5       0
6       0
7       0
8       0
9       0
10      0
```

This is the function, i am working with however it gives me false results. I think i somehow need to extract all the data where the condition completion = 1 is met and then apply the ifelse statement.

```
 df$overdue <- ifelse(df$completion == 1 & df$day >
 df$deadline, 1,0)
```

Data

```
df <- structure(list(completion = c(0, 0, 1, 1), day = c(1, 2, 3, 4
), deadline = c(2, 3, 2, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: That looks like a much better example. Would you mind updating the `dput` so it matches the sample data?

Comment: why is line 5 overdue if it is not completed? Your `ifelse` code looks fine to me.

Comment: @DanielO in my df, the output i get is wrong. The overdue variable does not match the condition i suggest.

Comment: @Lisam the 'Data' showed iwith `dput` is shorter one

Comment: can anybody see what i did wrong in the ifelse statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need an `ifelse`

```
data.frame(overdue = +(with(df1, completion == 1 & day > deadline)))
#    overdue
#1        0
#2        0
#3        1
#4        0
#5        0
#6        0
#7        0
#8        0
#9        0
#10       0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(completion = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L), day = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), deadline = c(2L, 
3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), activityid = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

<

Comment: @Lisam It is from the `dput` output.  For e.g. if you do `dput(head(mtcars))`, you get the structure output. the `L` suffix is to signify that it is an `integer`

Comment: I don't understand how OP gets a different output than this one with their original code.

Comment: @akrun also, i want the output to be dummy variables if the variable is overdue = 1

Comment: @Lisam What do you meant by dummy variables here.  Can you update your expected output

Comment: @akrun when running your data i get FALSE and TRUE statements, instead of 0 if  task is not overdue and 1 if task is overdue

Comment: @Lisam I had the `+(...)` which coerces the TRUE/FALSE to 1/0

Comment: @akrun, okay and how do i get a new variable in existing df instead of new dataframe, because it does nor run atm

Comment: @akrun done, thank you and this gets me the correct results, thank you

Comment: @DanielO  I am not sure either